# How to choose appropriate AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to deploy a website that uses Django on the server side and reactJs Frontend on AWS. I'm estimating traffic of about 40,000 per month. It happens that Amazon has several hosting packages. I like the EC2 instances but I don't know which particular instance will be suitable for me and being cost effective. I want to host for 6 months to get to understand the platform and later extends it if I'm comfortable with their services. The database isn't that robust. I'll also like to add updates at least two times a week.
Honestly, I haven't used AWS before and I don't even know if EC2 is the best for my project. Which of the packages will be best for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS EC2 is an IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) cloud model, and it's best suited for those who are starting to use cloud computing. We can say that it's similar to on-prem environments, you have almost full control over all aspects of computing like memory, storage, and networking, on the other hand, you need to manage them, and in some cases, you don't want or, you don't need to do. In your case, with the information provided, an EC2 seems to be the best choice, so you can safely try AWS (safely, because you will need to take care of costs, and on IaaS model you have more predictability) while learning about other services. The second step will depend on the specificities of your application like if stateful or stateless if needs to be scalable or not. Hope I have contributed.

Answer (score 3):

Your main choice is **Amazon EC2** (highly flexible) vs **Amazon Lightsail** (similar to a VPS).

Nobody can advise you on sizing your system, since it is totally dependent upon what your application does (video vs compute vs caching, etc) and how your users interact with the app. You should pick an Instance Type, **setup a test system that simulates typical usage** and then monitor how it runs.

Alternatively, pick something reasonably big, **run it in production and monitor for any issues**. If it all looks good, you could downsize the system.